# Wordpress to use Drupal users' credentials

Tags: users, login, user-registration

I have both Wordpress and Drupal installed on two domains. I want the users that register via Wordpress to be stored in Drupal's user table. Also, any login attempts should be checked against Drupal's database.

I don't have a lot of experience with either (though I'm fairly confident in my PHP skills). I am not looking for a way to mirror the users, but to actually tell Wordpress to use Drupal's database.

I think I have to rewrite the login and register methods on Wordpress. Am I wrong? And what's the best way to do this? (what files do I need to go into)?

Comment: If I were you, I'd split this into two questions - first ask at Drupal Answers your question about remote authentication (external site authenticating through Drupal).  Once you know how that works, then come back here and dig deeper into specifics.  It might be easiest to ignore WP's login functions altogether rather than attempt what is guaranteed to be a very messy integration between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use the hook [Register Form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form) (run at the end of the default rego form) to capture the data then `POST` the data to a Drupal page and/or run the mysql query ond the Drupal database.